# python3 manage.py makemigrations not working

Tags: python-3.x, manage.py, makemigrations

I can successfully run git clone 'my repository'

I can run 'pip3 install -r requirements.txt'; from the correct directory 'server'

When I run the command 'python3 manage.py makemigrations'; nothing happens.

When I run 'python3 -m pip show django', I get the following:

Name: Django
Version: 3.2.14
Summary: A high-level Python Web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design.
Home-page: https://www.djangoproject.com/
Author: Django Software Foundation
Author-email: foundation@djangoproject.com
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /home/theia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: asgiref, pytz, sqlparse
Required-by:

**My requirements.txt file:**

```
\\\
requests
Django
# changed to 20.1.0 to get rid of error
gunicorn==20.1.0
Pillow==8.0.1
ibm-cloud-sdk-core==3.10.0
ibm-watson==5.2.2
ibmcloudant==0.0.34
\\\
```

**my manage.py file:**

```
\\\
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djangobackend.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
         main()
\\\
```

If I run **'python manage.py makemigrations'**, I get the following error:

File "manage.py", line 17
) from exc
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

If I run 'python3 manage.py makemigrations', nothing happens.

My version of python is 2.7.17

I am working in a virtual lab through Skills Network Labs as part of the Coursera Full Stack Course (Theia; the lab is deleted at sign off), 'I run the command ps -ef | grep runserver', and get this:

theia       2018     279  0 13:22 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto runserver

so I don't think 'killing' the server would work.

INSTALLED_APPS is present in my settings.py folder.

I only have the single project running.

Ideas? I'm kind of new, so if you say, add such and such, can you be specific? same for command; thank you.

Comment: What you got when you run `python3 manage.py runserver` ?

Comment: nothing happens at all in the terminal. it just go's to the prompt. no error message or anything.

Comment: Please show your `settings.py`.